# Axis-labeling in R histogram and density plots; multiple overlays of density plots

Tags: r

I have two related problems.

**Problem 1**: I'm currently using the code below to generate a histogram overlayed with a density plot:

```
hist(x,prob=T,col="gray")
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,100, 20), labels=seq(0,100,20))
lines(density(x))
```

I've pasted the data (i.e. `x` above) [here](http://pastebin.com/upxgwb9e).

I have two issues with the code as it stands:

- the last tick and label (100) of the x-axis does not appear on the histogram/plot. How can I put these on?
- I'd like the y-axis to be of count or frequency rather than density, but I'd like to retain the density plot as an overlay on the histogram. How can I do this?

**Problem 2**: using a similar solution to problem 1, I now want to overlay three density plots (not histograms), again with frequency on the y-axis instead of density. The three data sets are at:

1. http://pastebin.com/z5X7yTLS
2. http://pastebin.com/Qg8mHg6D
3. http://pastebin.com/aqfC42fL

Comment: If you make the y axis be counts (which you can do after taking the time to read  `?hist`), then the `density` will probably be scaled so small it will barely register. You will need to multiply it by the total number of observations to make it on the same scale as the counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your first 2 questions:

```
    myhist <- hist(x,prob=FALSE,col="gray",xlim=c(0,100))
    dens <- density(x)
    axis(side=1, at=seq(0,100, 20), labels=seq(0,100,20))
    lines(dens$x,dens$y*(1/sum(myhist$density))*length(x))
```

The histogram has a bin width of 5, which is also equal to `1/sum(myhist$density)`, whereas the `density(x)$x` are in small jumps, around .2 in your case (512 even steps). `sum(density(x)$y)` is some strange number definitely not 1, but that is because it goes in small steps, when divided by the x interval it is approximately 1: `sum(density(x)$y)/(1/diff(density(x)$x)[1])` . You don't need to do this later because it's already matched up with its own odd x values. Scale 1) for the bin width of `hist()` and 2) for the frequency of x `length(x)`, as DWin says. The last axis tick became visible after setting the `xlim` argument.

To do your problem 2, set up a plot with the correct dimensions (`xlim` and `ylim`), with `type = "n"`, then draw 3 lines for the densities, scaled using something similar to the density line above. Think however about whether you want those semi continuous lines to reflect the heights of imaginary bars with bin width 5... You see how that might make the density lines exaggerate the counts at any particular point?

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've decided against using frequency on y-axis for the density overlay plots.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an aged thread, if anyone catches this. I would only think it is a 'good idea' to forego translating the y density to count scales based on what the user is attempting to do.

There are perfectly good reasons for using frequency as the y value. One idea in particular that comes to mind is that using counts for the y scale value can give an analyst a good idea about where to begin the 'data hunt' for stratifying heterogenous data, if a mixed distribution model cannot soundly or intuitively be applied.

In practice, overlaying a density estimate over the observed histogram can be very useful in data quality checks. For example, in the above, if I were looking at the above graphic as a single source of data with the assumption that it describes **"1 thing"** and I wish to model this as **"1 thing"**, I have an issue. That is, I have heterogeneous data which may require some level of stratification. The density overlay then becomes a simple visual tool for detecting heterogeneity (apart from using log transformations to smooth between-interval variation), and a direction (locations of the mixed distributions) for stratifying the data.