# Overlay histogram on top and right of a plot

Tags: r, plot, overlay, histogram

I am trying to create a plot similar to the one asked here: 
[Rotate histogram in R or overlay a density in a barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022675/rotate-histogram-in-r-or-overlay-a-density-in-a-barplot)

I am replacing the scatterplot with heatmap keeping everything else same without any luck. I tried to modify different parameters but it is not helping.

```
scatterBarNorm <- function(x, dcol="blue", lhist=20, num.dnorm=5*lhist, ...){
  ## check input
  stopifnot(ncol(x)==2)
  ## set up layout and graphical parameters
  layMat <- matrix(c(2,0,1,3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
  layout(layMat, widths=c(5/7, 2/7), heights=c(2/7, 5/7))
  ospc <- 0.5 # outer space
  pext <- 4 # par extension down and to the left
  bspc <- 1 # space between scatter plot and bar plots
  par. <- par(mar=c(pext, pext, bspc, bspc),
              oma=rep(ospc, 4)) # plot parameters


  ## scatter plot (removed this)
  #plot(x, xlim=range(x[,1]), ylim=range(x[,2]), ...)
  ##added this
  heatmap(x, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA)



  ## 3) determine barplot and height parameter
  ## histogram (for barplot-ting the density)
  xhist <- hist(x[,1], plot=FALSE, breaks=seq(from=min(x[,1]), to=max(x[,1]),
                                              length.out=lhist))
  yhist <- hist(x[,2], plot=FALSE, breaks=seq(from=min(x[,2]), to=max(x[,2]),
                                              length.out=lhist)) # note: this uses probability=TRUE
  ## determine the plot range and all the things needed for the barplots and lines
  xx <- seq(min(x[,1]), max(x[,1]), length.out=num.dnorm) # evaluation points for the overlaid density
  xy <- dnorm(xx, mean=mean(x[,1]), sd=sd(x[,1])) # density points
  yx <- seq(min(x[,2]), max(x[,2]), length.out=num.dnorm)
  yy <- dnorm(yx, mean=mean(x[,2]), sd=sd(x[,2]))
  ## barplot and line for x (top)
  par(mar=c(0, pext, 0, 0))
  barplot(xhist$density, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0, max(xhist$density, xy)),
          space=0) # barplot
  lines(seq(from=0, to=lhist-1, length.out=num.dnorm), xy, col=dcol) # line
  ## barplot and line for y (right)
  par(mar=c(pext, 0, 0, 0))
  barplot(yhist$density, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0, max(yhist$density, yy)),
          space=0, horiz=TRUE) # barplot
  lines(yy, seq(from=0, to=lhist-1, length.out=num.dnorm), col=dcol) # line
  ## restore parameters
  par(par.)
}

require(mvtnorm)
X <- abs(rmvnorm(1000, c(0,0), matrix(c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1), 2, 2)))
scatterBarNorm(X, xlab=expression(italic(X[1])), ylab=expression(italic(X[2])))
```

Comment: Is the [rasterVis](http://rastervis.r-forge.r-project.org/) package what you are looking for? A heatmap is essentially a raster.....